# Hot to read from local.settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.7

I have local.settings.json like below in my folder.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "DATABASE": "DW_TEST"
  }
}
```

When I try to read it `os.environ.get("DATABASE")`, I am getting None